# React-chartjs-2 chart component doesn't refresh when hook state changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-chartjs

I have this chart component which gets an `address` from its parent and it gets the `chartData` for that address from the hook `useData`. When a new address is passed in, the chart data does change but only the labels render for some reason. I'm wondering if there is a better way of doing this.

```
function Chart({ address }) {
  const { labels, Data: chartData } = useData(address);

  const data = (labels, chartData) => {
    return {
      labels: labels,
      datasets: [
        {
          label: "Line 1",
          data: chartData,
        },
      ],
    };
  };

  return <Bar id={address} data={data(labels, chartData)} redraw={true} />;
}
```

Comment: I use axios to get data from server and it works fine. I think the useData hook must be used with useEffect hook. You can check this for more info: https://justinmahar.github.io/react-use-analytics-api/useData